# How to change QML-model to C++ model?

Tags: c++, qt, qml

I have got a simple program with QML-model

```
import QtQuick 2.12
import QtQuick.Window 2.12
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.12
import QtQuick.Shapes 1.12
Window {
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480
    title: qsTr("Hello World")
    ListModel {
        id: lstmdl
        ListElement{
            name: "Arthur Morgan"
        }

        ListElement{
            name: "Dutch van der Linde"
        }

        ListElement{
            name:  "John Marston"
        }
    }

    Rectangle{
        width: parent.width / 3
        height: parent.height
        ListView{
            anchors.fill: parent
            model: lstmdl
            spacing: 9
            delegate: Text {
                text: name
            }
        }
    }
}
```

How to present this model in C++ and show it to QML. I know about I need to make a class, who inherit `QAbstractListModel` and implement some methods in that class. But

1. why these methods should be implemented specifically?
2. How do I know the methods that have to be implemented?
3. What does each of these methods do?

Comment: Read https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtquick-modelviewsdata-cppmodels.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, it should be noted that *I know about I need to make a class, who inherit QAbstractListModel and implement some methods in that class* is false, it is not necessary to create a new class that inherits from QAbstractListModel, for example the same can be implemented based on QStandardItemModel:

```cpp
#include <QGuiApplication>
#include <QQmlApplicationEngine>
#include <QQmlContext>
#include <QStandardItemModel>

enum CustomRoles{
    NameRole = Qt::UserRole + 1000
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication::setAttribute(Qt::AA_EnableHighDpiScaling);

    QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);

    QStandardItemModel model;
    model.setItemRoleNames({{CustomRoles::NameRole, "name"}});

    for(const QString & name: {"Arthur Morgan", "Dutch van der Linde", "John Marston"}){
        QStandardItem *item = new QStandardItem;
        item->setData(name, CustomRoles::NameRole);
        model.appendRow(item);
    }

    QQmlApplicationEngine engine;
    engine.rootContext()->setContextProperty("lstmdl", &model);
    const QUrl url(QStringLiteral("qrc:/main.qml"));
    QObject::connect(&engine, &QQmlApplicationEngine::objectCreated,
                     &app, [url](QObject *obj, const QUrl &objUrl) {
        if (!obj && url == objUrl)
            QCoreApplication::exit(-1);
    }, Qt::QueuedConnection);
    engine.load(url);

    return app.exec();
}
```

```
import QtQuick 2.12
import QtQuick.Window 2.12

Window {
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480
    title: qsTr("Hello World")
    Rectangle{
        width: parent.width / 3
        height: parent.height
        ListView{
            anchors.fill: parent
            model: lstmdl
            spacing: 9
            delegate: Text {
                text: name
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Note:** On the other hand, Qt provides documentation and examples on how to use C++ models in QML:

- [Using C++ Models with Qt Quick Views](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtquick-modelviewsdata-cppmodels.html)
- [Models and Views: AbstractItemModel Example](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtquick-models-abstractitemmodel-example.html), etc

---

1. why these methods should be implemented specifically?

   Because like any abstract class: It has methods that only define the behavior but do not implement it.
2. How do I know the methods that have to be implemented?

   That is clearly indicated by the [QAbstractListModel docs](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractlistmodel.html), so I will not repeat it but will point out some clarifications. If you only want a reading model you only need to implement the data, rowCount() and roleNames() methods. If you want to be editable you can implement the setData() method. For more detail read the class documentation.
3. What does each of these methods do?

   Same as above: Each method has indicates its usefulness and logic in the documentation.

Comment: For those catching this otherwise good answer: Do not use QStandardItemsModel in production code, just for your initial prototyping work. The thing is inherently (and incredibly) slow, and it only exists with this name because so many mistook the name of what was intended as a demonstration and prototyping tool as something supposed to be used for final implementations, and it can't be removed now, because of the source and binary compatibility promise.

Comment: Summary what we have in short algorithm:
1. The model stores objects.

2. Every object contains roles represented as text(for QML), and number(for C++). For example: a model of contacts book contains nameRole, surnameRole and numberRole.

3. In QML we use roles to creat a delegate to represent objects from model.
Is all this right?

Comment: @Bogdasar Yes, that is called MVC. See https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtquick-modelviewsdata-modelview.html

Comment: @eyllanesc Model-View-delegate.

Comment: @eyllanesc WOW! All this time (few months) I understood everything!!! BUT only in theory. And how we all know theory is nothing without a practice!!! StackOverflow can 't help me with this. Thanks, goodbye!